# Passing XML to Javascript to show markers in Google map

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a newbie to php and I'm trying to create a Google map based on this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 with a little twist. I've put up a search box and managed to output an XML based on the query.

I'm having a hard time passing the XML data from search.php to make markers in Google maps

here's my code

**for the form**

```
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="search.php"> 
 <input type="text" name="search" size="20"/>
 <input type="button" onClick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
 </form>
```

**For the search.php**

```
 <?php
  include("config.php");

    function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
    { 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
    return $xmlStr; 
    } 

    if(empty($_POST['search'])) {
 header("Location:map.html");

    }

    $query = " SELECT * FROM markers WHERE name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR address LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }

   header("Content-type: text/xml");

   // Start XML file, echo parent node
   echo '<markers>';

   // Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  }

  // End XML file
  echo '</markers>';

  ?>
```

**For the javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.479, 121.020),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("search.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/passing-xml-to-javascript-to-show-markers-in-google-map

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
  <title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map = null;

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function searchLocations(){
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var search_term = document.getElementById('search-term').value;
      jQuery.ajax({
        dataType :'xml', 
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'search.php?search_term='+search_term, 
        success:function(data){
          var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: point,
              icon: icon.icon
            });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          }
        }});
      return false;
    }
    //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
 <p>
  <form id="search-form" method="post" action="search.php"> 
   <input type="text" name="search" size="20" id="search-term"/>
   <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchLocations();" />
 </form>
</p>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

function xml_entities($value) {
    return strtr(
        $value, 
        array(
            "<" => "&lt;",
            ">" => "&gt;",
            '"' => "&quot;",
            "'" => "&apos;",
            "&" => "&amp;",
            )
        );
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['search_term'])){
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_REQUEST['search_term']));

    if($result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE name LIKE '%{$search_term}%' OR address LIKE '%{$search_term}%'")){

        $markers = array();

        while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            extract($row);
            $markers[] = "<marker name='".xml_entities($name)."' address='".xml_entities($address)."' lat='{$lat}' lng='{$lng}' type='{$type}' />";
        }

        if(count($markers)){
            header("Content-type: text/xml");
            echo '<markers>'.implode('', $markers).'</markers>';
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the help aSeptik, but still can't get it to work. change the $_POST to $_REQUEST and added the missing js script. What am I doing wrong.. I see yours working..

Comment: @via8321: i have added the php code and stripped to the bone the html file, try it with both file and let me know.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.. I tested your php file but didn't get any xml result.

Comment: @via8321: i have updated the php code pls try it, should work now.

Comment: It worked!! I've been dealing with this problem for days. Thanks a lot for the help @aSeptik. If you don't mind got another question, How can I display "No results found" if the query returned 0 results?

Comment: @via8321: you are welcome. pls check also the up arrow for a +1 for the challenge.. ;) thanks.

Comment: @aSeptic: I can't seem to check the up arrow for now. It said I need 15 rep to vote up.