# Passing XML to Javascript to show markers in Google map

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question is related to a previous question: Passing XML to Javascript to show markers in Google map asked by via8321 and asnwered by aSeptik on Mar 25 '14.

[[Passing XML to Javascript to show markers in Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643810/passing-xml-to-javascript-to-show-markers-in-google-map?rq=1][1])

The code is based on previous answer referred to above (see example demo: [http://so.devilmaycode.it/passing-xml-to-javascript-to-show-markers-in-google-map][1]

Was trying to create a search radius module where user selects a radius and locations are retrieved from a MySQL db and outputted as map and markers. I was having a similar problem to via8321 where I could get XML output (XML doc) but not render into a map and markers. The data was correct.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131458/google-store-locator-example-producing-xml-output-file-but-cannot-render-map-and?noredirect=1#comment48382245_30131458][1]

I used aSeptik's answer and was able to get the module working correctly on its own. Per via8321 and aSeptik's comments, the key was changing from POST or GET to REQUEST in collecting the form variable to pass to the MySQL query and changing the back-end php file from building nodes and save XML function to using xml_entities and .implode. I also changed my form input from a select list to a simple input field. It passes a radius to the SQL query.

Now, I am trying to integrate it into a larger application with a different MySQL database. But now I have the same problem as before. I can only get XML output, no map and markers. It seems like the identical problem as before.

Would anyone know what the specific issue or problem is? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. (Code is below):

Here is mapsearch.php that contains the front end form and map:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include_once("includes/config.php");
    $s_pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
    $sqlCommand  = "SELECT * from kusers_tbl WHERE PID = '$s_pid'";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlCommand);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $center_lat = $row[14];
    $center_lng = $row[15]; 
    $_SESSION['user_lat'] = $row[14];
    $_SESSION['user_lng'] = $row[15];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>Map Search</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var map = null;

        function load() {
          var center_lat = <?php echo ($center_lat); ?> 
          var center_lng = <?php echo ($center_lng); ?> 
          var center = new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat, center_lng);
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: center,
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          });
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }

        function searchLocations(){
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
          var searchterm = document.getElementById('searchterm').value;
          jQuery.ajax({
            dataType :'xml', 
            type: 'GET',
            url : 'mapsearchdb.php?searchterm='+searchterm, 
            success:function(data){
              var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
              for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var firstName = markers[i].getAttribute("firstName");
                var staddress = markers[i].getAttribute("staddress");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
                var html = '<p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
                firstName + '</a><br/>' + staddress;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: point
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
                    window.location.href = markers[i].url;
        });
                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
              }
            }});
          return false;
        }
        //]]>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
     <p>Enter your radius for your tenant search (in miles).
     <form id="searchform" method="post" action="mapsearchdb.php"> 
       <input name="searchterm" size="3" id="searchterm"/>
       <button type="submit" onclick="searchLocations();"/>Search</button>
     </form>
    </p>
     <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    </body>
```

Here is mapsearchdb.php the back-end php file that takes the radius input, center coordinates  calculates the nearest locations and pulls them from the db (SQL query from kusers_tbl) and produces the XML output:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("includes/config.php");
$s_pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
$center_lat = ( isset( $_SESSION['user_lat'] ) ? $_SESSION['user_lat'] : 44.98); # You could replace these "0"s with the
$center_lng = ( isset( $_SESSION['user_lng'] ) ? $_SESSION['user_lng'] : -93.26 ); # Lat/Lng of a default location.

function xml_entities($value) {
    return strtr(
       $value, 
       array(
            "<" => "&lt;",
            ">" => "&gt;",
            '"' => "&quot;",
            "'" => "&apos;",
            "&" => "&amp;",
           )
        );
    }
if(isset($_REQUEST['searchterm'])){
    $searchterm = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_REQUEST['searchterm']));

    // Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstName, staddress, latitude, longitude, usertype, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM kusers_tbl HAVING distance <= '%s' AND usertype='Renter' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($searchterm));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
$markers = array();

        while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            extract($row);
            $markers[] = "<marker firstName='".xml_entities($firstName)."' staddress='".xml_entities($staddress)."' latitude='{$latitude}' lng='{$longitude}' />";
        }

      if(count($markers)){
            header("Content-type: text/xml");
            echo '<markers>'.implode('', $markers).'</markers>';
        }

}   
?>
```

XML output (same format as previous question that I posted - just different data/table):

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<markers>
<marker firstName="Lucy" staddress="2014 Goodrich Ave." latitude="44.93792130" lng="-93.18552530"/>
<marker firstName="Bob" staddress="1250 Jefferson Ave." latitude="44.93056750" lng="-93.15305010"/>
</markers>
```

Comment: What does your xml look like?  Is it valid?

Comment: Don't know. Would love to know if it is or not. Have included the xml output. Tried to include the statement in the code block that's shown at the top of the browser: "This XML file does not appear . . . tree is shown below." But the editor apparently didn't want it there.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question, parsing an XML to create markers. See: [How to show location on a map taking longitude and latitude values from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222887/how-to-show-location-on-a-map-taking-longitude-and-latitude-values-from-xml/29223273#29223273)

Comment: Alex, tried it including marker.setMap(map) but no change. Still only xml. Also, tried mapbox earlier and got the same result. Could the problem be with the back-end php file "mapsearchdb.php" and how it's building the xml?

Comment: Also, geocodezip, I am new to XML. I don't know what's valid or not. Could you please take a look it and tell me if it is? Thanks in advance.